# How to implement sliding effect on jQueryUI Tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, syntax, tabs, effects

I have jQueryUI tabs set to fade between tabs. But I would like to apply other effects, perhaps sliding. But since I am a newbie to jQuery I cannot seem to get the syntax right.

This is what works right now:
 `$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle', duration:500} });`

This however does NOT work:
 `$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ fx: { slide: 'toggle',duration:500} });`

or this:
`$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ fx: { slide: 'toggle',direction:'down',duration:500} });`

I have also tried `slideUp`, `slideDown`, even `explode`..nothing other than opacity seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

$("#tabs").tabs({ 
    fx: { height: 'toggle', duration: 1000 }
});

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$("#tabs").tabs({fx:{height: "toggle"}}).tabs("slideDown", 500);
```

Comment: only the first part works (fx...) but still the slide down effect does not. BTW if you do just this: `$("#tabs").tabs("slideDown", 500);` It breaks the Tabs widget